# ngModal not working for input type checkbox inside ngFor

Tags: html, typescript, angular7

ngModal doesn't seem to work when using the checkbox inside an ngFor, while 
       repeating an array of objects like

[{"checked":true},{"checked":false}]

If we changed the checked property to true or false from the component, it's not reflecting in the UI, same logic will work for mdb-checkbox of md bootstrap.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  sampleObj = [
    {'checked': false, name: 'option 1'},
    {'checked': false, name: 'option 2'},
    {'checked': false, name: 'option 3'},
    {'checked': true, name: 'option 4'}
  ];

  sampleFunc(event, i) {
    if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
      alert(i);
      this.sampleObj[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of sampleObj; let i = index">
  <input type='checkbox' name='item{{i}}' [(ngModel)]="item.checked" (change)="sampleFunc($event, i)" /> 
  <label for='item{{i}}'><span>{{item.name}}</span></label>

</div>
```

Working example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3orv4w

Angular Version:

```
   Angular CLI: 7.1.1
Node: 10.14.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.1
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.1
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.1
@angular/pwa                      0.11.2
@angular/service-worker           7.1.2
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.1
@schematics/angular               7.1.1
@schematics/update                0.11.1
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. I used your stackblitz-Demo and it works?! Please be more precise concerning the behavior you expect.

Comment: @Lynx242 I meant based on the sampleObj's checked property the checkbox should work. ie from the component if we changed the checked property to true for suppose sampleObj[2], The third checkbox in UI should change it's status to true right ? since ngModel is used.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I got some appointments. Please find my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here you go. This is your stackblitz-class modified and commented.

What you can do in order to achieve your goal is to temporarily memorize the index of the currently clicked checkbox. I did this with the variable `marker`.

I hardly recommend to wait for the `ngAfterViewChecked()`-hook then before you start to manipulate the box, because this way you can make sure that you won't run in any timing issues if the page slows down somewhen.

Next step is to check whether the marker was set. And then you have to wrap your actual switch-back-code into a timeout-function. If you don't do so you'll run into this error:

**ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'model: true'. Current value: 'model: false'.**

That's it.

You can try to decrement the timeout further, in order to have the checkbox not even blink. But be always aware of the risk to run into the above mentioned error if you act too fast.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  // the clicked checkbox's index
  private marker: number = -1;

  sampleObj = [
    {'checked': false, name: 'option 1'},
    {'checked': false, name: 'option 2'},
    {'checked': false, name: 'option 3'},
    {'checked': true, name: 'option 4'}
  ];

  sampleFunc(event, i) {
    if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
      // memorize the clicked checkbox's index
      this.marker = i;
    }
  }

  toggle() : void {
    this.sampleObj[1].checked = !this.sampleObj[1].checked; 
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    // if a marker is set
    if (this.marker > -1) {
      // start the timeout and then reset the checkbox
      setTimeout (() => {
      this.sampleObj[this.marker].checked = !this.sampleObj[this.marker].checked;
      this.marker = -1;
      }, 20);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps. Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: Don't mention it.  ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've got a solution. Apparently, Angular doesn't treat the checked-state as a boolean internally.

I did the following:

I added a button to your HTML-file, right after the closing-tag `</div>`. Just for testing purposes.

```
<button (click)="toggle()">click me</button>
```

In the TypeScript-File I added a toggle-method with the following content.

```
toggle(): void {
    this.sampleObj[1].checked = !this.sampleObj[1].checked; 
}
```

And this does the trick.

Comment: Thanks Lynx your solution works, but still it's not working inside ngModelChange nor change event handlers. If we change the this.sampleObj[1].checked = !this.sampleObj[1].checked;it's not reflecting.

Comment: Sorry, but you kinda lost me. Your  `sampleFunc()` is called, whenever you click on one of these checkboxes. But I can't understand why you want to reset them to unchecked when they've just been checked? What is the strategy / usecase behind this?

Comment: PS: You can't switch the state back when `(change)` fires because you're in the `ngOnChanges()`-hook at this moment. Angular won't accept switching the value back at this particular state. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Is there anyway we can achieve ? Am able to work this within change event with mdb-bootstrap, but with typical input element, it's not working.